# What happens if I add money via commuter benefits to my card but don't use it all in the same month?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs

My work gives us $125 tax-free for commuting via the IRS commuter benefits scheme. Although I don't need to commute to and from work every day, I could use this $ to load up my commuter rail pass and use it when I need to.

What would be the consequences of taking advantage of the full $125 each month, but using perhaps only, say, $30 of it? What happens to the remaining $95? Can I roll it over and use it in another month where I might have to make more than $125 worth of commutes? Can I commute to a stop not near my work? (I will eventually use up all of it, just not in the same month.)

Comment: Which public transit system, and exactly what is the company purchasing for you? They all have their own rules, and they usually have multiple options from case equivalent to unlimited use for a specific amount of time; what happens will depend on what plan the company signs you up for.

Comment: I'm in the Bay Area, so a "Clipper Card" which can be used for multiple transit systems (Caltrain, BART, AC Transit, MUNI, etc.) is the common option around here. The company lets me choose from any of the available options up to $125 (anything more will be my contribution up to the IRS limit).

Comment: We use Wageworks, btw.

Comment: So does my employer, but there are multiple options through that program, since there are multiple options offered by the transit system.

Comment: @keshlam I'm asking if I can just load my card with the money and use it for whatever transit option I think is the best on a given day, and, in addition, roll it over if I don't use it all in the same month.

Comment: In my experience they tend to issue these as standard Monthly Passes. Whether that can be used on all modes of transportation depends on which pass you get and your transit authority's policies for that kind of pass, and they don't accumulate value from month to month .... But on the other hand you may be able to use it for personal travel as well.

Answer (score 2):

I few years ago my company in the Washington DC area allowed employees to contribute their own pre-tax funds. The system at the time wasn't sophisticated enough to prevent what you are suggesting. The money each month was put on a special credit card that could only be used at certain types of locations. You could load it onto the Metro smart trip card, and use it for many months. Many people did this, even though the IRS says you shouldn't.

But eventually the program for the federal employees changed, their employer provided funds were put directly onto their Smart Trip card. In fact there were two buckets on the card: one to pay for commuting, and the other to pay for parking. There was no way to transfer money between buckets. The first day of the new month all the excess funds were automatically removed from the card;and the new funds were put onto the card.

If your employer has a similar program it may work the same way. HR will know.

Answer (score 0):

In the San Francisco bay area I know the region is putting to use Clipper cards. If you load them with clipper cash that money sticks around until you ultimately use it. The card itself maxes out at like $300 but any excess funneling into the card is kept with Clipper and shows up in your account as like some itemized deposit pending to distribute to your card once the card's balance drops below the limit to the amount that is pending deposit.

If you however use the money for something like a month pass which is only good for that month and you don't use the pass to break even then you lose that money.